# Spring Boot 2 Hibernate Update not inserting

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to update an object that already exists in my database. Saving an object works fine, but when calling an update, my logs show a select statement but no update. The following is my code.

Entity

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name = "items")
    public class Items implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3607451001182083512L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer iditems;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "idcategories")
        private Categories categories;

        @Size(min = 1, max = 35)
        private String name;

        @Size(min = 0, max = 100)
        private String description;

        private double price;
        private int hidden;
        private String upc;

        @OrderColumn
        @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = "itemsextrascat", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "iditems") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idextrascat"), })
        private Set<Extrascat> extrascat = new HashSet<Extrascat>();



    Getters and Setters
    }
```

Service

```
@Service("itemsService")
public class ItemsService {

    @Autowired
    private ItemsDao itemsDao;


    // CREATE OR UPDATE ITEM
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public void createOrUpdate(Items items) {
        itemsDao.createOrUpdate(items);
    }

    // CREATE OR UPDATE ITEM
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public void update(Items items) {
        itemsDao.update(items);
    }

}
```

DAO

```
@Transactional
@Component("itemsDao")
public class ItemsDao {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;


    // CREATE OR UPDATE ITEM
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public void update(Items items) {
        Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();

        session.unwrap(Session.class).merge(items);
    }
}
```

I've tried using save update persist merge all to no avail. I've also tried changing where my `@Transactional` is located per what I read on other post. I also made sure my methods were not private to make sure `@Transational` was being evoked. I was able to solve the issue by implementing a Repository which allows me to update the entity. However, I don't really want both DAO and Repository in my code. Any ideas as to why the Dao implementation does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making your Dao way too complex. First why use native hibernate where a plain `EntityManager` would suffice. Why use an `EntityManagerFactory` to manage your own `EntityManager`. Lastly you are in a Spring managed environment don't use `openSession` or `createEntityManager` as that will get you a non transactional one.

That being said you can remove most of your code.

```
@Transactional
@Component("itemsDao")
public class ItemsDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    // CREATE OR UPDATE ITEM
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public void update(Items items) {
       em.merge(items);
    }
}
```

This is all you need. Basically don't use `openSession` as that will give you a new `Session` for hibernate. If you do this enough eventually you will also end-up with an unresponsive application as all DB connections are used. This because you are opening the session but never closing it.

I would suggest however, as you are using Spring Boot and JPA to simply use Spring Data JPA en let that handle all of this.

```
public interface ItemsRepository extends CrudRepository<Items, Long> {}
```

Then in your code simply call the `save` method on the `ItemsRepository` and Spring Data JPA will do all the nasty stuff for you.

Comment: I was updating an old app that was first built on the spring framework and hibernate 3 or 4. When i first updated to spring boot 2 i tried to crudely get everything to work and needed a session. Your solution works. Thanks for explaining the issue in layman's terms.